# Bigquery Entity Tag

Tags: go, google-bigquery

When I loaded my data from Cloud Storage into Bigquery, the `click_url` field turned into `Record` type when get created even though it's a string (maybe because of the `noindex` not sure tho). When I try to insert the data into BigQuery using `Inserter`. I got this error message:

> Cannot convert std::string to a record field:optional .Msg_0_CLOUD_QUERY_TABLE.Msg_1_CLOUD_QUERY_TABLE_click_url click_url = 1

Table in bigquery:

[image]

Schema:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
type Product struct {
        Name     string `datastore:"name" bigquery:"name"`
        ClickUrl string `datastore:"click_url,noindex" bigquery:"click_url"`
        DateAdded time.Time `datastore:"date_added" bigquery:"date_added"`
}

func insertRows(data interface{}) error {
        projectID := "my-project-id"
        datasetID := "mydataset"
        tableID := "mytable"
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.NewClient: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()

        inserter := client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID).Inserter()
        if err := inserter.Put(ctx, data); err != nil {
                return err
        }
        return nil
}

func main() {
        product := Product{"product_name", "click_url", "date_added_value"} // Example data from datastore
        if err := insertRows(product); err != nil {
              fmt.Println(err)
        }
}
```

What should I put on the entity tag `"bigquery:click_url"` to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Because the ClickUrl in BigQuery is a STRUCT type, which has key-value pairs.

Maybe try this?

```
type Product struct {
        Name     string `datastore:"name" bigquery:"name"`
        ClickUrl struct {
          String  string
          Text  string
          Provided  string
        } `datastore:"click_url,noindex" bigquery:"click_url"`
        DateAdded time.Time `datastore:"date_added" bigquery:"date_added"`
}
```

Comment: I would love to change the structure but I can't since it would affect all of our code. The impact of the changes is huge. But I'm really confused why the `click_url` turned out to be a struct(even though it's a string) when I loaded the data from cloud storage into bigquery.

Comment: yes, I think it's probably because of the `noindex` in datastore.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will just create another struct and pass all data from the original struct even though its not a good approach but I'll try.

Comment: I have a question. I've successfully run the `insert` but when I checked the data in the table I can't seem to find it. Will it reflect realtime once the data is inserted?